# How to connect to Socket.IO

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I've already connected to Socket.IO but I'm still getting an error.

I create a Socket.IO manager:

```
class SocketIOManager: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()

    func establishConnection() {
        socket.connect()
    }

    func closeConnection() {
        socket.disconnect()
    }

    func join(nickname: String) {
        socket.emit("join", nickname)
    }


    func exitChatWithNickname(nickname: String, completionHandler: () -> Void) {
        socket.emit("userdisconnect", nickname)
        completionHandler()
    }


    func sendMessage(message: String, withNickname nickname: String) {
        socket.emit("messagedetection", nickname, message)
    }


    func getChatMessage(completionHandler: @escaping (_ messageInfo: Message) -> Void) {
        socket.on("message") { (dataArray, socketAck) -> Void in
            var message = Message()

            let eventDataTemp = dataArray[0] as? [String: Any]
            //let eventData = eventDataTemp![0] as? Dictionary<String, String>;
            print(eventDataTemp)
            message.idUser = eventDataTemp?["senderNickname"] as! String
            message.message = eventDataTemp?["message"] as! String
            completionHandler(message)
        }
    }


    private func listenForOtherMessages() {
        socket.on("userjoinedthechat") { (dataArray, socketAck) -> Void in
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "userWasConnectedNotification"), object: dataArray[0] as! [String: AnyObject])
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my error

```
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: error with data: ["Tried emitting when not connected"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your error clearly states that your app is trying to `emit while its not connected to socket`. You need to make sure your connection to the socket has been established before you make any emits.
Generally you would want to connect to socket when your app starts running and close the connection when the app is closed or goes into background.

This is how I would implement SocketIO in my app.

Step 1: Create a Socket Manager File called `SocketManager.swift` and add this code.

```
import SocketIO

class SocketIOManager: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()

    let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "YOUR_SOCKET_URL")!, config: [.log(true), .connectParams([:])])

    var socket: SocketIOClient!

    override init() {
    super.init()
    
        socket = manager.defaultSocket
    
        //Listener to capture any message that your server emits for "emitMessage" key. You can add multiple listeners to capture various emits from your server.
        socket.on("emitMessage") { (data, ack) in
            print("Socket Ack: \(ack)")
            print("Emitted Data: \(data)")
            //Do something with the data you got back from your server.
        }
    }

    //Function for your app to emit some information to your server.
    func emit(message: [String: Any]){
        print("Sending Message: \([message])")
        socket.emit(sendKey, with: [sendMsg], completion:nil)
    }

    //Function to establish the socket connection with your server. Generally you want to call this method from your `Appdelegate` in the `applicationDidBecomeActive` method.
    func establishConnection() {
        socket.connect()
        print("Connected to Socket !")
    }

    //Function to close established socket connection. Call this method from `applicationDidEnterBackground` in your `Appdelegate` method.
    func closeConnection() {
        socket.disconnect()
        print("Disconnected from Socket !")
    }
}
```

Step 2: In your `AppDelegate.swift` file add the following.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.closeConnection()
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.establishConnection()
}
```

Step 3: When ever you want to make an emit to the server you can do this from anywhere in your app.

```
SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.emit(message: "message": "This is a test message")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
add at global

```
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:8080")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
let socket = manager.defaultSocket
```

call this method

```
import SocketIO


func callSocket()
{
   socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
       print("socket connected")
   }

   socket.on("currentAmount") {data, ack in
       guard let cur = data[0] as? Double else { return }

       socket.emitWithAck("canUpdate", cur).timingOut(after: 0) {data in
           socket.emit("update", ["amount": cur + 2.50])
       }

       ack.with("Got your currentAmount", "dude")
   }

   socket.connect()
}
```

visit: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift

Comment: I tried this but it not working  
 this my node server wich I would socketIO connect

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

  console.log('user connected');
  
  socket.on('join', function(userNickname) {
  
          console.log(userNickname +" : has joined the chat "  );
  
          socket.broadcast.emit('userjoinedthechat',userNickname +" : has joined the chat ");
      })